# Why I cannot install Android SDK r18? repository-6.xml cannot be found in Google Server

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

This is the log:
Fetching http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Validate XML
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml
Done loading packages.

In fact, repository-6.xml is not properly downloaded. So the packages which need to be installed is not listed in the dialog.

I've tried checked the option:"Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...", but still cannot update or install the SDK tools and platforms.

So I copy the url "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml" in browser and open it, which display a 404 page.
But the file "repository-5.xml" in the same url directory is available.

Is anyone installed SDK r18 success?

Comment: i was getting timeout for  17 so did this>>>>went to Help>Install new then URL for "Work with " and enter

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse GO to:
Windows-Check for updates and eclipse will find the update for the android sdk if there i one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has be resolved. It seems that it's google's own probelm, after 4 hours I can install and update now.